# sencha touch charts tooltip display

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha touch donut chart. Now I am looking for tooltip display in donut charts sections. After I searched on internet, i found that there is no tooltip library in sencha touch charts like we do have in EXTJS.

please let me know if we can use EXTJS tooltip code into sencha touch charts, if not then please help me with some links, examples for sencha touch charts tooltips.

i am using this code in my sencha touch donut chart JS but this is not working:

```
   var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: 'donut-chart',
        html: '<font size="2" color="white"><span style="padding-left:2px"><B>Electronics &nbsp;&nbsp; $15.3m</B></span> <br><br> <span style="padding-left:2px">%Total &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13%</span></font>',
        width: 150,
        height: 6,
        Border: 'false',
        bodyStyle: 'background-color: teal;',
        style: 'background-color: white;opacity: 0.5;'
     }); 
     tip.showAt(200, 100);
```

please help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In [`Sencha Touch Pie Charts`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie), there's a property `donut` to set the *pie chart* as *donut chart*.

Default value is `false`. You can set this property to `true`

```
donut: true,
```

and then use the `tips` property of `PieChart` like this,

```
tips: {
  trackMouse: true,
  width: 140,
  height: 28,
  renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + ' views');
  }
},
```

Comment: yes, i did same thing already. i used this in my "Series" section of donut chart and i am testing this in chrome browser and when i scroll my mouse over my donut chart anywhere, i don't see any tooltip.

Comment: do i need to test this in ipad directly?

Comment: Hi.... just one more thing, should i put "tips" section inside series section of chart or where should i put this "tips" section. Also, let me know if i need to include any JS class name in "Ext.require" section for this. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but posting my solution as it might be helpful for someone.

I am using donut charts, so this solution works for me. What I did is a custom tooltip done with DIV element in HTML and position it based on the center of PIE.

Once DIV is ready and styled,

Under `Items:[]`, create piegrouping and reposition your tooltip on `onSelectionChange` event of grouping as follows:

```
{
    type: 'piegrouping',
    onSelectionChange: function(me, items) {
        if (items.length) {
            if(items.length<2)
            {
                var tipX=items[0].middle.x - 35;
                var tipY=items[0].middle.y - 35;

                $('.tooltip').css('left', tipX + 'px');
                $('.tooltip').css('top', tipY + 'px');

                $('.tooltip h1').html(sum);
                $('.tooltip').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('.tooltip').hide();
            }
        }
        else {
            $('.tooltip').hide();
        }
}
```